# Unusable Trait with where clause

Tags: rust, traits

I have the following Code in Rust

```
use num_complex::Complex64;

pub trait RealComplex where Self : std::iter::Sum, for<'a,'b> &'a Self : std::ops::Mul<&'b Complex64, Output=Complex64> {}

impl RealComplex for f64 {}
impl RealComplex for Complex64 {}

struct A<T> {
    a : T
}

impl<T : RealComplex> A<T> {
    fn get(self) -> T {
        self.T
    }
}
```

Link in Playground : https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=410e0410353bc2fbcefcdce3dcaf2621

The Trait `RealComplex` should mean that the Type implement `std::iter::Sum` and that I can multiply the Reference of this Type by a Reference of `Complex64`.

But it seems I am unable to use this trait at all, without the compiler complaining.

What I want to accomplish: I want a generic Matrix Type which implements just Matrix-Vector Multiplication like this:

```
struct SparseMatrix<T> {
    data : Vec<Vec<T>>
}

impl<T : RealComplex> SparseMatrix<T> {
    fn multByVec(&self, &[Complex64]) -> Vec<Complex64> {
       ...
    }
}
```

This should be generic over `f64` and `Complex64`

Comment: It seems that HRTB and supertraits don't work well together because you have to rewrite the bound: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d1a5d43accf410ebe5cd7ab3786966d7

Comment: @FrenchBoiethios that is exactly the thing I wanted to avoid by defining the trait `RealComplex`

Comment: @Unlikus I know, just saying. That seems to be at least a limitation, or a bug.

Comment: @FrenchBoiethios so I should add it to the issue tracker on github.com?

Comment: I would ask in the forum before